# javascript wait until cookie equals "1"

Tags: javascript, cookies, wait

Is there any way in JavaScript to wait until a cookie equals "1".

I have a cookie named `mim0` and I need my function to wait until `mim0` equals "1".

Also `mim0` is set on a different page.

Comment: How is it set? Can you not change the code there to do what you want to do?

Comment: No, you generally don't "wait" in JavaScript.

Comment: What changes the cookie?

Comment: what is the event which changes the cookie to '1'?

Comment: Unless you have push capabilities or the two pages are linked somehow (eg, same user having the two different pages in same browser), you're stuck with checking the existing cookies in an interval.

Comment: @freestock.tk the cookie is set through php

Comment: Use an event listener maybe?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scotthannen/4cpmn0n5/10/) containing what I use when I need to wait for something. It's an extension to [q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), so you'd need that reference too. This is just for convenience. You can really just do this yourself with q.js, any other promises library, or native ES6 promises.

The usage would be

```
Q.WaitForExpression([expression that returns true])
    .then(function()
    {
        //do whatever
    });
```

It's not blocking your thread. It's checking the expression at intervals, and the inner function executes when (if) that expression returns true.

I recommend learning about promises in general. They make this sort of asynchronous "do this then that" behavior much, much easier.